# Is it possible to use references as react component's prop or state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to create react table component which values are derived from single array object. Is it possible to control the component from view side? My goal is that every user using this component in their web browsers share the same data via singleton view object.

Program modeling is like below.

1. Database - there are single database in server which contain extinct and independent values.
2. DataView - there are singleton View class which reflects Database's table and additional dependent data like (sum, average)
3. Table - I'll build react component which looks like table. And it will show View's data with supporting sorting, filtering, editing and deleting row(s) feature (and more). *Also it dose not have actual data, only have reference of data from View(Via shallow copy -- This is my question, is it possible?)*

My intentions are,
- When user changes value from table, it is queried to DB by `View`, and if succeed, `View` will refer updated data and change it's value to new value and notify to `Table` to redraw it's contents. -- I mean `redraw`, not `updating value and redraw`.
- When values in View are changed with DB interaction by user request, there are no need to update component's value cause the components actually dose not have values, only have references to values (Like C's pointer). So only View should do is just say to Component to redraw it's contents.

I heard that React's component `prop` should be immutable. (Otherwise, `state` is mutable) My goal is storing references to component's real value to it's `props` so that there are no additional operation for reflecting View's data into Table.

It is concept problems, and I wonder if it is possible. Since javascript dose not support pointer officially(Am I right?), I'm not sure if it is possible.

View class is like below,

```
const db_pool = require('instantiated-singleton-db-pool-interface')
class DataView {
  constructor() {
    this.sessions = ['user1', 'user2'] // Managing current user who see the table
    this.data = [ // This is View's data
    {id:1, name:'James', phone:'12345678', bank:2000, cash:300, total:2300,..},
    {id:2, name:'Michael', phone:'56785678', bank:2500, cash:250, total:2300,..},
    {id:3, name:'Tyson', phone:'23455432', bank:2000, cash:50, total:2300,..}
    ] // Note that 'total' is not in db, it is calculated --`dependent data`
  }
  notifySessionToUpdate(ids) {
    // ids : list of data id need to be updated
    this.sessions.forEach((session) => {
      session.onNotifiedUpdateRow(ids) // Call each sessions's 
    })
  }
  requestUpdateRow(row, changed_value) {
    // I didn't write async, exception related code in this function for simple to see.
    update_result = db_pool.update('UPDATE myTable set bank=2500 where id=1')
    if (update_result === 'fail') return; // Do Nothing

    select_result = db_pool.select('SELECT * from myTable where id=1') // Retrieve updated single data which object scheme is identical with this.data's data
    for (k in Object.keys(select_result)) {.ASSIGN_TO_row_IF_VALUE_ARE_DIFFERENT.} // I'm not sure if it is possible in shallow copy way either.
    calc.reCalculateRow(row) // Return nothing just recalculate dependant value in this.data which is updated right above.
    // Notify to session
    this.notifySessionToUpdate([1]) // Each component will update table if user are singing id=1's data if not seeing, it will not. [1] means id:1 data.
    return // Success
  }
... // other View features
}
```

Regarding session part, I'm checking how to implement sessionizing(?) the each user and it's component who is communicating with server. So I cannot provide further codes about that. Sorry. I'm considering implementing another shallow copied `UserView` between `React Component Table` and `DataView`(And also I think it helps to do something with user contents infos like sorting preference and etc...)

Regarding DB code, it is class which nest it's pool and query interface.

My problem is that I'm not familiar with javascript. So I'm not sure shallow copy is actually implementable in all cases which I confront with.

I need to think about,
1. Dose javascript fully support shallowcopy in consistent way? I mean like pointer, guarantee check value is reference or not.
2. Dose react's component can be used like this way? Whether using `props` or `state` Can this be fullfilled?

Actually, I strongly it is not possible to do that. But I want to check your opinions. Seems it is so C language-like way of thinking.

Comment: I mean, what you're essentially describing is redux. I'd look into redux and how it alters components based on an object changing, with props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redraw mean re-render. You can expose `setState()` or `dispatch()` functions from `Table` component and call them on `View` level using refs:

```js
function View() {
  const ref = useRef();

  const onDbResponse = data => ref.current.update(data);

  return (
    <Table ref={ ref } />
  );
}

const Table = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
  useImperativeHandler(ref, {
    update: setData
  });

  ...
});
```

Anyway i don't think it's a good practice to update like that. Why can't you just put your data in some global context and use there?

```js
const Context = React.createContext({ value: null, query: () => {} });

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState();
  const query = useCallback(async (request) => {
    setValue(await DB.request(request));
  }, [ DB ]);

  const context = { value, query };

  return <Context.Provider value={ context }>{ children }</Context.Provider>;
}

const useDB = () => useContext(Context);

const View = () => {
  const { request } = useDB();

  request(...);
}

const Table = () => {
  const { value } = useDB();

  ...
}
```

Comment: I need to check your answers in more detailed way, but for now, can you describe more about your opinion below? Anyway, really thank you.

Comment: I tested with your codes and others, and decide to use second one you advice to me. Thanks. First one is deadly slow on my environment (Which has lots of lots of data to render in single page)

Comment: From top to bottom rendering cause massive lacks